# Spring Security Login not working when using jdbcAuthentication

Tags: java, mysql, spring-security, spring-boot

inMemoryAuthentication() is working fine. But i am a newbie to spring security and i want to authenticate from the mysql database.

```
.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("vikram.mscsw@gmail.com").password("vikram").roles("ADMIN");
```

I need the exact same thing but from mysql table. I need authenticate with the userid typed on login page. I tried the following

```
.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery("select user_id, password from logindetails where user_id=?");
```

and the stacktrace was:

```
ERROR 8608 --- [io-9393-exec-10] w.a.UsernamePasswordAu
henticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the
user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceExcept
on: null
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationPro
ider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.
.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsA
thenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.jav
:143) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenti
ate(ProviderManager.java:167) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenti
ate(ProviderManager.java:192) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuth
nticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java
93) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticati
nProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[s
ring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.
oFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.R
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(Cs
fFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterI
ternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0
3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceF
lter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.
.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManag
rIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [
pring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(F
lterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterCha
nProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(
elegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Delega
ingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal
RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInte
nal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.REL
ASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterIntern
l(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInter
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELE
SE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePer
equestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapper
alve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContext
alve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentic
torBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.
ava:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.
ava:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVa
ve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.ja
a:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHtt
11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndp
int.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoi
t.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [n
:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [
a:1.8.0_66]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskT
read.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadU
ersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:216) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:
.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadU
erByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:173) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4
0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationPro
ider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.
.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Can you guys help me on what am doing wrong

Comment: Have you set DataSource?

Comment: No am not setting Datasource configuration at all. Can u please tell me what should i do to make this work

Comment: Your query is wrong. It requires 3 columns (username, password, enabled) instead of 2. So rewrite your query to `select user_id as username, password, 1 as enabled from logindetails where user_id=?`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have created a column for status of user. once user status is set to set to false i should not allow the user to login. How can i edit the query from 1 as enabled to check the status of the user from Database

Comment: replace the '1` with the column name.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to get the employee id of the user who is logging in and concatenate with the /home end point. How can i do that ?
`int id=1;
 /*int id = employeedaoimpl.getIdByUserId(e.getUserId());*/
 public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {  
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/home/"+ id);
    }
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a production environment you probably want a pooling data source, but this will get you started:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource= new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    // adjust the following to your environment
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("secret");
}
```

([Spring Boot can also help.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html))

Use the data source in JDBC authentication:

```
.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource())
```

Comment: But all these configuration are written in a property file can I somehow use that ?

Comment: @Vikram You can try to autowire DataSource.

Comment: The above solution worked, the problem was enabled parameter was missing in my code. Thank you so much